# Eventos do teclado no C# em textbox

Tags: c#

Olá, pessoal, sou novato em C#. Bem, a fins didáticos, estou desenvolvendo esta calculadora que vocês vêm na imagem. Ela está quase pronta, porém, falta apenas a função de quando eu digito um numero do teclado, o mesmo aparece no textbox da calculadora. Como faço isso? Na net eu so acho exemplos pra pressionar um botão e aparecer um MessageBox, quero digitar um no teclado e aparecer 1 na calculadora.

Segue o código - [importado do GitHub](https://github.com/SidSan97/calculadora-C-/blob/master/calculadora.txt):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Calculadora
{
    public partial class Calculadora : Form
    {
        string operador;
        Double a = 0;
        bool validar;

        public Calculadora()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = (Button)sender;
            Tela.Text = Tela.Text + button.Text;
        }

        private void button_Click_CE(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Tela.Text = "";
        }

        private void button_Click_Adc(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (validar == true)
            {
                a = a + Convert.ToDouble(Tela.Text);
                label1.Text = Convert.ToString(a) + "+";
                Tela.Text = "";
                operador = "+";
            }
            else
            {
                label1.Text = Tela.Text + buttonAdc.Text;
                a = Convert.ToDouble(Tela.Text);
                Tela.Text = "";
                operador = "+";
                validar = true;
            }
        }

        private void button_Click_Sub(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (validar == true)
            {
                a = a - Convert.ToDouble(Tela.Text);
                label1.Text = Convert.ToString(a) + "+";
                Tela.Text = "";
                operador = "-";
            }
            else
            {
                label1.Text = Tela.Text + buttonSub.Text;
                a = Convert.ToDouble(Tela.Text);
                Tela.Text = "";
                operador = "-";
                validar = true;
            }
        }

        private void button_Click_Multi(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (validar == true)
            {
                a = a * Convert.ToDouble(Tela.Text);
                label1.Text = Convert.ToString(a) + "*";
                Tela.Text = "";
                operador = "*";
            }
            else
            {
                label1.Text = Tela.Text + buttonMulti.Text;
                a = Convert.ToDouble(Tela.Text);
                Tela.Text = "";
                operador = "*";
                validar = true;
            }
        }

        private void button_Click_Div(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (validar == true)
            {
                a = a / Convert.ToDouble(Tela.Text);
                label1.Text = Convert.ToString(a) + "/";
                Tela.Text = "";
                operador = "/";
            }
            else
            {
                label1.Text = Tela.Text + buttonDiv.Text;
                a = Convert.ToDouble(Tela.Text);
                Tela.Text = "";
                operador = "/";
                validar = true;
            }
        }

        private void button_Click_C(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Tela.Text = "";
            label1.Text = "";
            a = 0;
            validar = false;
        }

        private void button_Click_Igual(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (operador == "+")
            {
                label1.Text = label1.Text + Tela.Text + "=";
                Tela.Text = Convert.ToString(a + Convert.ToInt32(Tela.Text));
            }
             else if (operador == "-")
            {
                label1.Text = label1.Text + Tela.Text + "=";
                Tela.Text = Convert.ToString(a - Convert.ToSingle(Tela.Text));
            }
             else if (operador == "*")
            {
                label1.Text = label1.Text + Tela.Text + "=";
                Tela.Text = Convert.ToString(a * Convert.ToSingle(Tela.Text));
            }
             else if (operador == "/")
            {
                label1.Text = label1.Text + Tela.Text + "=";
                Tela.Text = Convert.ToString(a / Convert.ToSingle(Tela.Text));
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }        

    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não coloque o código em arquivo externo deixe-o direto na pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

Mude a propriedade **KeyPreview** do form para **true**

E no evento KeyPress do Form:

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    // Precisa fazer para aceitar apenas caracteres validos
    Tela.Text += e.KeyChar;

    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro defina a propriedade [`KeyPreview`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview?view=netframework-4.7.2) do formulário para `true` de forma que as mensagens do teclado sejam recebidas pelo formulário antes que elas atinjam os controles no formulário.

Coloque um evento [`OnKeyPress()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keypress?view=netframework-4.7.2) no Formulário, use a propriedade `KeyPressEventArgs.KeyChar` para mapear a tecla pressionada e ajuste a propriedade `KeyPressEventArgs.Handled` como`true` para informar o manipulador de eventos do sistema que saiba que o formulário já resolveu o evento e não o propague para os outros componentes.

O código vai ficar aproximadamente assim:

```
void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
                switch (e.KeyChar)
                {
                    case (char)48: Tela.Text = Tela.Text + "0"; break;
                    case (char)49: Tela.Text = Tela.Text + "1"; break;
                    case (char)50: Tela.Text = Tela.Text + "2"; break;
                          // .
                          // .     Os caracteres ASCII de 48 até 57 representam os números de 0 a 9. 
                          // .     Para evitar repetições no exemplo usei as reticências.
                          // .
                    case (char)57: Tela.Text = Tela.Text + "9"; break;

                    // Manipula o `+`
                    case (char)43: button_Click_Adc(this, EventArgs.Empty); break;
                    // Manipula o `-`
                    case (char)45: button_Click_Sub(this, EventArgs.Empty); break;
                    // Manipula o `*`
                    case (char)42: button_Click_Multi(this, EventArgs.Empty); break;
                    // Manipula o `/`
                    case (char)47: button_Click_Div(this, EventArgs.Empty); break;
                    // Manipula o `=`
                    case (char)61: button_Click_Igual(this, EventArgs.Empty); break;

                }
                e.Handled = true;

}
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo Augusto. Muito obrigado, mano!!